# Julia - how does @inline work? When to use function vs. macro?

Tags: julia

I have many small functions I would like to inline, for example to test flags for some condition:

```
const COND = UInt(1<<BITS_FOR_COND)
function is_cond(flags::UInt)
    return flags & COND != 0
end
```

I could also make a macro:

```
macro IS_COND(flags::UInt)
    return :(flags & COND != 0)
end
```

My motivation is many similar macro functions in the C code I am working with:

```
#define IS_COND(flags) ((flags) & COND)
```

I repeatedly timed the function, macro, function defined with @inline, and the expression by itself, but none are consistently faster than the others across many runs.  The generated code for the function call in 1) and 3) are much longer than for the expression in 4), but I don't know how to compare 2) since `@code_llvm` etc. don't work on other macros.

```
1) for j=1:10 @time for i::UInt=1:10000 is_cond(i); end end
2) for j=1:10 @time for i::UInt=1:10000 @IS_COND(i); end end
3) for j=1:10 @time for i::UInt=1:10000 is_cond_inlined(i); end end
4) for j=1:10 @time for i::UInt=1:10000 i & COND != 0; end end
```

Questions: What is the purpose of `@inline`?  I see from the sparse documentation that it appends the symbol `:inline` to the expression `:meta`, but what does that do, exactly?  Is there any reason to prefer a function or macro for this kind of task?

My understanding is that a C macro function just substitutes the literal text of the macro at compile time, so the resulting code has no jumps and is therefore more efficient than a regular function call.  (Safety is another issue, but let's assume the programmers know what they're doing.)  A Julia macro has intermediate steps like parsing its arguments, so it's not obvious to me whether 2) should be faster than a 1).  Ignoring for the moment that in this case the difference in performance is negligible, what technique results in the most efficient code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If the two syntaxes result in exactly the same generated code, should you prefer one over the other?  **YES**.  Functions are vastly superior to macros in situations like this.

- Macros are powerful, but they're tricky.  You have **three** errors in your `@IS_COND` definition (you don't want to put a type annotation on the argument, you need to interpolate `flags` into the returned expression, and you need to use `esc` to get the hygiene correct).
- The function definition just works as you expect.
- Perhaps more importantly, the function works just as *others* would expect. Macros can do *anything*, so that `@` sigil is a good warning for "something beyond normal Julia syntax is occurring here." If it's behaving just like a function, though, might as well make it one.
- Functions are first-class objects in Julia; you can pass them around and use them with higher order functions like `map`.
- Julia is built on inlined functions. Its performance depends on it! Small functions typically don't even need the `@inline` annotation — it just does it on its own.  You can use `@inline` to give the compiler an extra nudge that a bigger function is especially important to inline… but often Julia is good at figuring it out on its own (like here).
- Backtraces and debugging works better with inlined functions than macros.

---

So, now, do they result in the same generated code?  One of the most powerful things about Julia is your ability to ask it for its "intermediate work."

First, some set up:

```
julia> const COND = UInt(1<<7)
       is_cond(flags) = return flags & COND != 0
       macro IS_COND(flags)
           return :($(esc(flags)) & COND != 0) # careful!
       end
```

Now we can start looking at what happens when you use either `is_cond` or `@IS_COND`. In actual code, you'll be using these definitions within other functions, so let's create some test functions:

```
julia> test_func(x) = is_cond(x)
       test_macro(x) = @IS_COND(x)
```

Now we can start moving down the chain to see if there's a difference.  The first step is "lowering" — this simply converts the syntax to a limited subset to make life easier for the compiler.  You can see that at this stage, the macro gets expanded but the function call still remains:

```
julia> @code_lowered test_func(UInt(1))
LambdaInfo template for test_func(x) at REPL[2]:1
:(begin
        nothing
        return (Main.is_cond)(x)
    end)

julia> @code_lowered test_macro(UInt(1))
LambdaInfo template for test_macro(x) at REPL[2]:2
:(begin
        nothing
        return x & Main.COND != 0
    end)
```

The next step, though, is inference and optimization.  It's here that function inlining takes effect:

```
julia> @code_typed test_func(UInt(1))
LambdaInfo for test_func(::UInt64)
:(begin
        return (Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.not_int)((Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.and_int)((Base.sle_int)(0,0)::Bool,((Base.box)(UInt64,(Base.and_int)(x,Main.COND)) === (Base.box)(UInt64,0))::Bool))))
    end::Bool)

julia> @code_typed test_macro(UInt(1))
LambdaInfo for test_macro(::UInt64)
:(begin
        return (Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.not_int)((Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.and_int)((Base.sle_int)(0,0)::Bool,((Base.box)(UInt64,(Base.and_int)(x,Main.COND)) === (Base.box)(UInt64,0))::Bool))))
    end::Bool)
```

Look at that!  This step in the internal representation is a little messier, but you can see that the function got inlined (even without `@inline`!) and now the code looks exactly identical between the two.

We can go farther and ask for the LLVM… and indeed the two are exactly identical:

```
julia> @code_llvm test_func(UInt(1))       | julia> @code_llvm test_macro(UInt(1))
                                           | 
define i8 @julia_test_func_70754(i64) #0 { | define i8 @julia_test_macro_70752(i64) #0 {
top:                                       | top:
  %1 = lshr i64 %0, 7                      |   %1 = lshr i64 %0, 7
  %2 = xor i64 %1, 1                       |   %2 = xor i64 %1, 1
  %3 = trunc i64 %2 to i8                  |   %3 = trunc i64 %2 to i8
  %4 = and i8 %3, 1                        |   %4 = and i8 %3, 1
  %5 = xor i8 %4, 1                        |   %5 = xor i8 %4, 1
  ret i8 %5                                |   ret i8 %5
}                                          | }
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks.  Code introspection utilities didn't work on the macro by itself, but I didn't consider wrapping the macro in a test function.
Question: Why is it bad to annotate types of macro arguments?

Comment: It's not necessarily bad, it's just not doing what you're expecting. Macro argument types refer to the syntax tree representation and not the actual types of run time values.  E.g., `@foo(1)` could dispatch to `macro foo(::Int)`, but `x=1; @foo(x)` dispatches to `foo(::Symbol)` and `@foo(Int(1))` dispatches to `foo(::Expr)`. These distinctions aren't typically helpful, so that's why you almost never want to do that.